# SQL Delete query showing, but no action

Tags: php, sql, database, sql-delete

I have a SQL delete button after every record shown on my page. I have exactly what the button should do, but it's not working! I even echo the `$sql` to make sure it's correct and it displays the following:

```
DELETE * FROM recensies WHERE ID ='508a7a732ef67' AND email ='info@*****.nl'
```

When I look at the record in PHPmyAdmin I can see that there is a record with exactly this information, but on the other had that had to be, here is my code, I'm sure you'll see what I mean.

```
<?php

// Up here I connect to my DB, no problems there..

$query  = "SELECT * FROM recensies ORDER BY timestamp DESC"; 
$result = mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_error());

if (isset($_POST['verwijderen'])) 
{

    $IDdelete = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['ID']);
    $emaildelete = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['email']);

    $sql = "DELETE * FROM recensies "
         . "WHERE ID ='$IDdelete' AND email ='$emaildelete'";

    mysql_query($sql);

    echo $sql;
}

while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
{

?>
```

```
<form method="post">
<tr>
<td><?php echo $row['cijfer']; ?></td>
<td><input type="text" name="ID" value="<?php echo $row['ID']; ?>"></input></td>
<td><?php $newb = substr($row['beoordeling'], 0, 30); echo $newb; ?>..</td>
<td><?php echo $row['voornaam']; ?> <?php echo $row['achternaam']; ?></td>
<td><input type="text" name="email" value="<?php echo $row['email']; ?>"></td>
<td><?php $datum = date("j/n/y", strtotime($row[timestamp])); echo $datum; ?></td>
<td><input type="submit" value="Verwijderen" name="verwijderen"></td>
</tr>
</form>

<?php

}

?>

</table>

</div>

</div>
```

I just can't find my error!

Comment: Delete always mean whole row that is why sql does not allow to mention * or any field names. Delete means remove not erase. If you do not specify the row by using where then delete from sometable.. deletes the all rows.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you need to remove the * from the delete statement, so like this:

```
DELETE FROM recensies WHERE ID ='508a7a732ef67' AND email ='info@*****.nl'
```

Comment: Thanks, that fixed it, since you were the first to answer, I'll mark this one as the accepted one!

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name right you are, I was quoting from [w3schools](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_delete.asp) but looks like they are wrong again...

Comment: w3schools is known to publish very low quality. I just skimmed through some pages and it took me only 2 minutes to spot more errors.

Answer (score 3):

I don't know if it is your problem, but the DELETE syntax does not require a column list (* in your query):
you should write

```
DELETE FROM recensies WHERE ID = ...
```

no *

Answer (score 1):

Change

```
$sql = "DELETE * FROM recensies WHERE ID ='$IDdelete' AND email ='$emaildelete'";
```

to

```
$sql = "DELETE FROM recensies WHERE ID ='$IDdelete' AND email ='$emaildelete'";
```

Remove the `*`.

Try

```
mysql_query($sql);
echo mysql_error();
```

You should have an error that says

> You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that
>   corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use
>   near '* from recencies' at line 1:

Comment: Thanks! The extra * was the problem!